# Classes in Python: __str__ method and list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-2.7, class

I got this task at school:
"Complete the Animal class to have and a class variable animals (list) and two instance variables, name (str) and number (int). You need to implement **init** and **str** methods"
This what I did:

```
class Animal:

    animals = []
    number = 0

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name  
        Animal.number =+1

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{Animal.number}. {self.name.capitalize()}"
```

The following is the test that I should fulfill:

```
Animal.animals.clear()

dog = Animal('dog')
assert dog.name == 'dog'
assert dog.number == 1
assert str(dog) == '1. Dog'

cat = Animal('cat')
assert cat.name == 'cat'
assert cat.number == 2
assert str(cat) == '2. Cat'
```

I do not understand how to use the list in this case (also how to fill it) and how to keep the number updated. I am a beginner so please keep a simple language, thank you so much.

Comment: Since this is a coding-specific question, it is imperative that you state exactly which version of Python you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add to the animals list when a new animal instance is created, inside the init.

```
class Animal:

    animals = []
    number = 0

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name  
        Animal.animals.append(name)
        Animal.number += 1 # '+=' not '=+'

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{Animal.number}. {self.name.capitalize()}"
```

If you don't want the same animal in the list twice you can do:

```
if name not in Animal.animals:
    Animal.animals.append(name)
```

Comment: Thank you! it was exactly what I needed :D

Answer (score 0):

In short:

- `x = +1` ==> `x = 1`
- `x += 1` ==> `x = x + 1`

So change `Animal.number = +1` to `Animal.number += 1`.